# Drag Subtraction Formula for Excel : [ Aj − Fixed Cell ] for multiple j

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please forgive me for any analogous questions that have already been posted.

I desire: A1 = A27 − B1
A2 = A1 − B1
A3 = A2 − B1....

So I input in A1 the formula `A27 − B23` and then dragged it downwards. Howbeit, the result from Excel is and differs from that desired :

`A2 = A28 − B2

A3 = A29 − B3

A4 = B30 − B4....`

How could I remedy this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input in A1 the formula `A27 - B1`.

Then, also manually input A2 formula `$A1 - $B$1` and now drag A2 downwards.

You then should have:

```
A1 = A27 - B1
A2 = $A1 - $B$1
A3 = $A2 - $B$1
```

Notice that the `$` works like an anchor.

Comment: Much obliged. +1